Double Vs Single Bow Tie Transmission Gate Symbol
Is there any difference between two symbols (at the below link) or there totally identical at a functionality level and the only difference is visual just for aesthetic purposes?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate#/media/File:Transmission_gate_bowtie_symbol_variants.svg


Seems a comment of mine disappeared. Perhaps my mistake. Or the question was deleted. Regardless, again, look here at Figure 3.

I looked at the figure 3 and I read the text below but I couldn't find a clear answer about the use and the difference or no between two symbols.
